# reshaping data frame r

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Simple reshaping, I have the following data:

```
df<-data.frame(Product=c("A","A","A","B","B","C"), Ingredients=c("Chocolate","Vanilla","Berry","Chocolate","Berry2","Vanilla"))
df
Product Ingredients
1   A   Chocolate 
2   A     Vanilla
3   A       Berry
4   B   Chocolate
5   B      Berry2
6   C     Vanilla
```

I want a column for each unique value of "ingredient", for example:

```
df2
Product Ingredient_1 Ingredient_2 Ingredient_3
A       Chocolate       Vanilla        Berry
B       Chocolate       Berry2         NULL
C       Vanilla         NULL           NULL
```

Seems trivial enough, I tried reshape but I keep getting counts (not the actual values of "ingredients"). Ideas?

Comment: Show the code that you tried that didn't work. You're basically reshaping your data from "long" to "wide" format. There are many, many questions out there already on this topic. Are you sure you thoroughly searched for existing answers before posting a new question?

Comment: I tried: dcast(df, Product ~ Ingredients, value.var = "Ingredients"), but it creates a column for each product

Comment: @MrFlick What's so unclear about this question? OP said they tried `reshape` without success. And is clear why- because it's not such a simple reshaping problem. If you can find a dupe, close the question. If not, why should the OP be able to?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Mostly because "i tried reshape" was very unclear. If you're having trouble with code, show the code you tried and give the exact error. From the comment above, it looks like they were not using `reshape()` but where using the `reshape` (maybe `reshape2`) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Ingredient := paste0("Ingredient_", seq_len(.N)), Product]
dcast(df, Product ~ Ingredient, value.var = "Ingredients")
#    Product Ingredient_1 Ingredient_2 Ingredient_3
# 1:       A    Chocolate      Vanilla        Berry
# 2:       B    Chocolate       Berry2           NA
# 3:       C      Vanilla           NA           NA
```

---

Alternavely, we could do this with the sexy `dplyr/tidyr` combination

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Product) %>%
  mutate(Ingredient = paste0("Ingredient_", row_number())) %>%
  spread(Ingredient, Ingredients)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# 
#   Product Ingredient_1 Ingredient_2 Ingredient_3
# 1       A    Chocolate      Vanilla        Berry
# 2       B    Chocolate       Berry2           NA
# 3       C      Vanilla           NA           NA
```

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of sharing alternatives, here are two more:

**Option 1**: `split` the columns and use `stri_list2matrix` to create your wide form.

```
library(stringi)
x <- with(df, split(Ingredients, Product))
data.frame(Product = names(x), stri_list2matrix(x))
#   Product        X1        X2      X3
# 1       A Chocolate Chocolate Vanilla
# 2       B   Vanilla    Berry2    <NA>
# 3       C     Berry      <NA>    <NA>
```

**Option 2**: Use `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package to generate an ".id" column, then `dcast` it. The "data.table" package is loaded with "splitstackshape", so you can directly call `dcast.data.table` to do the reshaping.

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast.data.table(getanID(df, "Product"), 
                 Product ~ .id, value.var = "Ingredients")
#    Product         1       2     3
# 1:       A Chocolate Vanilla Berry
# 2:       B Chocolate  Berry2    NA
# 3:       C   Vanilla      NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R `reshape`

```
df$Count<-ave(rep(1,nrow(df)),df$Product,FUN=cumsum)
reshape(df,idvar="Product",timevar="Count",direction="wide",sep="_")

#  Product Ingredients_1 Ingredients_2 Ingredients_3
#1       A     Chocolate       Vanilla         Berry
#4       B     Chocolate        Berry2          <NA>
#6       C       Vanilla          <NA>          <NA>
```

Comment: You may also be interested in `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package. It creates a column named `".id"` that are the "counts", so you can do: `reshape(getanID(df, "Product"), direction = "wide", idvar = "Product", timevar = ".id")`. +1